# Python: Remove last row in dataframe with "if loop"

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

This is probably a very trivial question, but I've been struggling on it for a while. Let's say I have a dataframe (D) and I want to remove the last row if it's equal to the penultimate row, so I've got:

```
In [10]: D= pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

In [11]: D
Out[11]: 
            A  B  C
2012-11-29  0  0  0
2012-11-30  1  1  1
2012-12-01  2  2  2
2012-12-02  3  3  3
2012-12-03  4  4  4
2012-12-04  5  5  5
2012-12-05  6  6  6
2012-12-06  7  7  7
2012-12-07  8  8  8
2012-12-08  8  8  8
```

My guess would be something like:

```
diff=D[len(D)-1:]==D[len(D)-2:]


def change(D):  
    if (diff==0):
        D = D[:len(D)-1]

D=change(D)
```

The only result of this code is that my dataframe D disappears. Can anyone please help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `diff`? What does your function return if `diff!=0`?

Comment: sorry I've edited the code, forgot about it

Comment: But the second part of my question stays (and it answers your original question).

Comment: `diff` will never be an `int`, so `diff == 0` will always be `False`, so not sure what you think that is doing.

Comment: if I use diff!=0, the dataframe D still disappears..

Comment: so my idea is: if the difference between those two rows is null, it means that the two rows are equal, therefore I want the last row to disappear

Comment: "difference between the two rows is null" what exactly does that mean? I think you want `(df.iloc[-1,:] == df.iloc[-2,:]).all()`

Comment: But you do not compare the last two rows, you compare the last row to the last two rows.

Comment: And you DF always disappears because your `change()` method does not return anything, So whatever you pass as an argument it's output will be `None`. This is what @DYZ was trying to point out.

Comment: I see, it turns out it was trivial then. Thank you very much